# Linguistics science-fiction story by James Tiptree, Jr

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, languages

A while ago I stumbled on a list of science fiction with linguistic themes.  I'd quite like to re-find the list, but I remember little more about it than that it mentioned *Babel-17* by Delany, and a short story by James Tiptree, Jr.; and, on the assumption that it's hard to find the list based just on those recollections, I'm asking here instead what the Tiptree story was.

My recollection is that this story revolved around a version of the Sapir–Whorf hypothesis, and that much of it was set in a jungle—I think I remember characters disembarking from, or fleeing to, a canoe at some point—but I can't remember more about the plot than that.  I read the story probably about 15 years ago, in a compilation of short stories, but unfortunately I can't even remember whether the compilation was entirely of Tiptree stories, or whether it had many sci-fi authors' stories.  Whatever it was, I think it was a later compilation, not the original publication of the story.

Comment: "The Women Men Don't See" has is set in the jungle/swamps of the Quintana Roo, and has two women leaving in a skiff at the end, but the story is not particularly about linguistics IIRC.

Comment: https://outofeverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/ill-be-waiting-for-you-when-the-swimming-pool-is-empty-review/ - This one has a universal translator. Lots of nonsense about linguistics here

Comment: @OrganicMarble, from reading the plot description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Women_Men_Don%27t_See), [that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/linguistics-science-fiction-story-by-james-tiptree-jr#comment762487_276500)'s so close to the plot I'm remembering that I'm wondering if it *was* a collection of Tiptree fiction that I was reading, and if I just mistakenly overlaid the plot of that one on the story I am remembering.  I'll see if I can find collections in which that story appeared and look what else is in their tables of contents.

Comment: I suspect that if there were story by Tiptree about Sapir-Whorf issues, it would have been discussed in a post of comment here:  https://languagehat.com/  However, a Google search for "site:languagehat.com Tiptree" turns up multiple mentions of the author, but nothing like the story you are describing.

Comment: @Buzz, [re](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/linguistics-science-fiction-story-by-james-tiptree-jr#comment762502_276500), did you mean to link a specific Languagehat post?

Comment: @LSpice No, just the main site.  Here's the link for the site search I did though:  https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alanguagehat.com+Tiptree

Comment: Does your list include [A Rose for Ecclesiates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Rose_for_Ecclesiastes), by Roger Zelazny? If not it's a regrettable omission.

Comment: @SimonCrase, [re](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/linguistics-science-fiction-story-by-james-tiptree-jr#comment762560_276500), the list is not my own, just one I found.  I can't find it any more, so I cannot say whether it includes your suggestion, but I will take that as a recommendation.

Answer (score 10):

Could it have been a story by a different author that was collected in The James Tiptree Award Anthology series? If so, [Looking through Lace](https://www.tor.com/2014/10/07/short-fiction-spotlight-the-james-tiptree-award-anthology-1-part-2/) by Ruth Nestvold may be the story you seek.  It was published in The James Tiptree Award Anthology 1 in 2005.

From [Bookshop.org](https://bookshop.org/p/books/looking-through-lace-ruth-nestvold/12685879):

> As the only woman on the first contact team, xenolinguist Toni Donato
> expected her assignment on Christmas would be to analyze the secret
> women's language -- but then the chief linguist begins to sabotage her
> work. What is behind it? Why do the men and women have separate
> languages in the first place? What Toni learns turns everything she
> thought they knew on its head. Originally published in Asimov's in
> 2003, "Looking Through Lace" was a finalist for the Tiptree and
> Sturgeon awards. The Italian translation won the Premio Italia for
> best work of speculative fiction in translation in 2007.

George Mason University has a [pdf copy](https://mason.gmu.edu/%7Eataylor/dvd_project/Readings/LookingThroughLace.pdf).

Comment: @Valorum, [re](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/linguistics-science-fiction-story-by-james-tiptree-jr#comment762504_276503), although I think it's not the story I mentioned (I distinctly remember the story being by Tiptree, and I remember the book in which I read it being a library copy with a binding so old that I'm almost positive it wasn't from 2005 … but I could be wrong!), the [linked](https://www.tor.com/2014/10/07/short-fiction-spotlight-the-james-tiptree-award-anthology-1-part-2/) plot description seems a pretty good match to what I described.